# Getting a 429 HTTP response in the network tab

Tags: json, zendesk-api, http-status-code-429

Is there something wrong with this code? Getting a 429 response and being rate limited by API. Is my loop to blame for this?

```
function getCat(from_locat){

var art_count = 0,
section_to_display = '';
if (!from_local) {
    $.getJSON('/api/v2/help_center/sections.json').success(function(data) {
        sections = data.sections;
        sec_count = data.count;
    }).then(function() {
        $.each(sections, function(section) {
            if (document.location.toString().match(sections[section].id) !== null) {
                    sections[section].isactive = 'active'; // section heading active?
                }
                $.getJSON('/api/v2/help_center/sections/' + sections[section].id + '/articles.json?draft=false').success(function(data) {
                    $.each(data.articles, function() {
                        if (document.location.toString().match(this.id) !== null) {
                            this.isactive = 'active'; // activate this
                            section_to_display = this.section_id;
                        }
                    });
                    sections[section].articles = data;
                    art_count++;
                    if (art_count === sec_count) {
                        renderNav(sections, section_to_display);
                        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                            var cache_expiry = moment().add(20, 'minutes').format('X');
                            sessionStorage.setItem('cache_expiry', cache_expiry);
                            sessionStorage.setItem('sections', JSON.stringify(sections));
                        }
                    }
                });
```

});

Comment: At least it's not [status 418](https://httpstatuses.com/418)...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have two loops in there, so the complexity/big "O" of the program grows quadratically. So, if `sections` has just 10 elements, your code consumes the said API at least (10^2) = 100 times. That consumption rate will quickly result in a 429 for any API. So, try to reduce your code's complexity.

Now however, your loops are making more requests than the said API allows in a given time frame. To attend to more requests, some APIs require you to be an authenticated user or have authentication tokens. For example, GitHub's API [limits requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) as follows:

> ### Rate Limiting
>
> For requests using Basic Authentication or OAuth, you can make up to 5,000 requests per hour. For unauthenticated requests, the rate limit allows you to make up to 60 requests per hour. Unauthenticated requests are associated with your IP address, and not the user making requests.

So, check if the API has such an authentication system that will enable you to make more requests.